# Flip horizontally only one background image

Tags: css

I have a header with two background images (one at each side). This way:

HTML:

```
<header>
    ...
</header>
```

CSS:

```
header {
    ...
    background-image: url(http://placehold.it/50x50), url(http://placehold.it/50x50);
    background-position: top left, top right;
    background-repeat: no-repeat, no-repeat;
}
...
```

See [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q1rf735s/).

For now I use two pictures and, as both pictures are identical but flipped horizontally, I want to use only one picture and use CSS to flip the other picture. To save some bandwidth...

On the web I found that I can use `transform: scaleX(-1);` to do the flip. But how to apply it at only one background image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

demo - http://jsfiddle.net/q1rf735s/1/

instead use pseudo element `:before` and `:after`

```css
header {
  width: 500px;
  height: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
}
header:before,
header:after {
  content: url(http://placehold.it/50x50), url(http://placehold.it/50x50);
  display: block;
  float: left;
}
header:after {
  transform: scaleX(-1);
}
header ul {
  margin: 0 50px;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}
header li {
  float: left;
}
header a {
  width: 100px;
  height: 33px;
  padding-top: 17px;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #333;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Foo</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Bar</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Foz</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Baz</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```